# How to Encode Javascript String into code128 for use with Libre Barcode 128?

Tags: javascript, barcode, code128

I'm using [Libre Barcode 128](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+128+Text) from Google Fonts to generate barcodes on a webpage. If I wanted to encode a string so that it was properly displayed with this font, how would I do that?

For example, I know that code128 barcodes need a checksum of some kind, and start/stop characters. However, the Libre Barcode project has no documentation about how this is calculated, nor how their characters map to glyphs.

Barcodes generated using the font alone will not scan. What steps are necessary to implement Code 128 barcode generation using Libre Barcode Fonts?

Comment: People are flagging this as "off topic", I don't understand why, it seems like a perfectly reasonable question.  Can someone explain what I am missing?

Comment: They probably think your question is overly broad.  This was the explanation 3 out of 4 times. - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: They want to see this... "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I think the problem is that it is impossible to create Code 128 barcodes that will scan without access to the start (B) and stop characters (which I found no mention of on the Libre Barcode Google font page) and you have to generate a checksum. My recommendation is find another Code 128 library or use the Libre Code 39 font which restricts you to uppercase alpha and numeric data.

Comment: This was fantastically helpful, thank you. I see the problem with the start/stop characters now, and have filed an issue on the Libre Barcode Github project asking for documentation. https://github.com/graphicore/librebarcode/issues/14

Comment: Thanks, @xd1936. If you could edit your question to reflect the more specific concern you had with generating the checksum and the start and stop characters, I will try to get the question cleared from on-hold status so I can include a javascript snippet that calculates Code 128 checksums for input strings. Then we can get the Libre Barcode people more directed towards including support for the high ASCII codes for starting, stopping, etc.

Comment: Here's a codepen that solves the problem: https://codepen.io/notionovus/pen/BmvQJE .

Comment: here an open source implementation for generating start and stop 
https://github.com/Holger-Will/code-128-encoder

Comment: I find this question to be well written and it describes the problem I had just today.  This is also a top hit on SO for this topic.  Thanks to the comments I learned that the string needs to have start/stop and checksum.  I switched from code 128 to the more simple code 39. Just put an '*' before and after your text. And the Libre Barcode 39 works